# How to pass a function as an argument to other function? My code is given below

Tags: python, function, class, object, robotics

this is the code for RRT algorithm

import sys
import pygame
import random, math
from math import sqrt, atan2, cos, sin
from pygame.locals import *

class RRT(object):

```
x = 0
y = 0
X_dimension = 0
Y_dimension = 0
Window_size = 0
EPS         = 0
Max_nodes   = 0 
nodes       = list()
K_ESCAPE    = True
KEYUP       = True
QUIT        = True

def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

#parameters
    self.X_dimension = 1280                                #length of the window
    self.Y_dimension = 1280                                  #breadth of the window
    self.Window_size = [self.X_dimension, self.Y_dimension]  #Window size
    self.EPS         =  7000                                #EPSILON or Incremental Distance 
    self.Max_nodes   = 100                                  #maximum number of nodes
    self.nodes       = list()
    self.QUIT        = QUIT
    self.KEYUP       = KEYUP
    self.K_ESCAPE    = K_ESCAPE


#function for calculating euclidean distance
def Calculate_Distance(self,x,y):

    x = [10,20]
    y = [15,30]  
    return sqrt((x[0]-y[0])*(x[0]-y[0])+(x[1]-y[1])*(x[1]-y[1]))

    pass 

def Initiate_Sampling(self,x,y):

    self.EPS = 7000 

    if Calculate_Distance(x,y) < 7000:
        return y
    else:
        theta = atan2(y[1]-x[1], y[0]-x[0])
        return x[0] + self.EPS*cos(theta), x[1] + self.EPS*sin(theta)

#Function for displaying the output
def Start_The_Game(self):

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_node(Window_size)

    caption = pygame.display.set_caption("performing RRT")

    white = 255, 240, 200
    black = 20, 20, 40
    screen.fill(black)

#Main Function
def Node_Generation(self, nodes):
    self.nodes      = []
    self.QUIT       = QUIT
    self.KEYUP      = KEYUP
    self.K_ESCAPE   = K_ESCAPE

    #nodes.append(X_dimension/2.0, Y_dimension/2.0)

    nodes.append(0.0, 0.0)
    pygame.init()

for i in range(Max_nodes):
    rand = random.random()*640.0, random.random()*480.0
    nn = nodes[0]

for p in nodes:
    if dist(p,rand) < dist(nn,rand):
        nn = p
        newnode = step_from_to(nn,rand)
        nodes.append(newnode)
        pygame.draw.line(screen,white,nn,newnode)
        pygame.display.update()
        print (i, "  ", nodes)

for j in pygame.event.get():
    if j.type == QUIT or (j.type == KEYUP and j.key == K_ESCAPE):
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit("GAME OVER")
```

path = RRT(10,15)

path.Calculate_Distance(10,15)

path.Initiate_Sampling(path.Calculate_Distance(10,15))

path.Start_The_Game()

path.Node_Generation()

#

My query - I want to pass Calculate_Distance function as an argument to the Initiate_Sampling function to compare it with EPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access member function via `self` the same way you would access other class members within the class. i.e.

```
self.Calculate_Distance
```